# 'Me' Keyword not Referring to Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, keyword

The "Me" keyword in Access 2003 has recently started behaving differently. I can no longer refer to Controls within a Form by typing, say: "Me.Combobox1 = " 
I can, however, still control it by referring to the Form directly by typing "Form1.Controls("Combobox1") = " - This shows that the Control is *definitely* present on the Form in question.

This is specific to one project, and may be linked to the following question [Inconsistent behavior for Me keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643652/inconsistent-behavior-for-me-keyword)

As in the above question, there *are* ActiveX controls present in my Database but, even after deletion, the "Me" keyword still retains its strange behaviour.

Can anyone think why this is happening / how to reverse it? Or a way to find out exactly what the "Me" is now referring to?

It's more annoying / time-consuming than anything else...

Thanks

Comment: Does your code compile? Sometimes autocomplete goes wonky when the code has a compile error.

Comment: It doesn't any more because all previous Me keywords have stopped working. It did previously.

Comment: Have you tried [decompiling the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application)?

Comment: Have you backed up, compacted and repaired and then decompiled?

Comment: I've just followed a process for decompling I've found online (I've never did this previously). As I'm using Access 2003, I didn't get any confirmation that the decompiling was successful - is this correct?
If so, it still won't compile now.

Comment: Don't you have a variable/fieldcontrol somewhere in your app also called "me" ? Try adding some `debug print me.name` in your forms code. You could also generate the Documentation to a PDF and search it for "me".

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think you can actually set Me as a variable? Nothing has came up in my search.

Comment: To further confuse things, Debug.Print Me.Name returns the name of the form. I've also used Me.Controls(ControlName) with success - This helps a little bit as it's faster than typing the full form name but, ideally, I'd still prefer to use Me.ControlName

Comment: Although I've found a solution (posted below), do you think this could be a sign of corruption in the database? I might copy the forms and modules to a new project to be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, but I've got no idea why it's worked.

I have deleted the latest form that I had created (which only contained 3 ComboBoxes - no code). There was nothing special about the form, and nothing was incorrectly labelled as "Me".